# How to make WebView transparent in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I am using Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView to render html content over a user control. I want the webview to be transparent so that user control is be completely visible.

But there is no property in webview to set background transparent like we have webview.DefaultBackground property in UWP..
Kindly help me out.

Please let me know is it possible to make webview transparent in WPF?

Comment: I don't think it is. But there is a feature request on webview2. https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback/issues/328

Comment: Thanks @Andy, but webview2 is still in preview :(. do no know till when it will make be available in production.

Comment: This is 2020 still Microsoft has no way for this. Sad to digest. :(

Comment: Is there any progress to incorporate this feature in upcoming SDK release?

Comment: 2021: It seems they're working on it with a working Win32 prototype. Let's hope they don't find any blockers for WinForms/WPF: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/328#issuecomment-755562112